# Что значит выражение "на руках"?

Tags: семантика

Что значит выражение "на руках"? Пример: данные на руках.
Как можно сказать это по-другому?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это модификация *фразеологизма* "выдать на руки", который фиксируется толковыми словарями. В данном случае "на руках" = "**выданы на руки**" (возможно, поэтому их нет на месте). В деловой речи это означает, что какие-либо материалы, имеющие постоянное место хранения, **переданы** кому-либо **в личное распоряжение**. Это могут быть библиотечные книги, медицинская карта поликлиники, папка с личным делом и т. п. "Данные" в вашем примере, скорее всего, находятся на физическом носителе, все экземпляры которого розданы пользователям на время.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше давать не словосочетание, а всё предложение, тогда можно понять, что именно имеется ввиду.

В целом «на руках» это фразеологизм. В Словаре русского языка Евгеньевой есть определение:

> **На руках у кого** (быть, иметься) — в наличии.
>
> - *Но даже и этих денег на руках у нас еще не было.* В. Беляев, Старая крепость.

Таким образом «данные на руках» значит, что данные у кото-то есть в наличии.

В словаре Ушакова есть устаревшее, но подходящее значение «руки»:

> **Употребляется как символ обладания, владения, власти.**
>
> - ...взял власть в свои руки.
> - Иметь, держать кого-что-нибудь в своих руках.
> - Выпустить из рук (инициативу, руководство и т. п.).
> - Переходить из одних рук в другие или из рук в руки (от одного обладателя к другому).
> - Побывать во многих руках (у многих владельцев).
> - Деньги в руках (имеются, получены).
> - **У меня на руках осталось сто рублей.**
> - **У меня на руках три козыря (в карточной игре).**
> - Вернуться с пустыми руками (ничего не имея).
> - Брать себя в руки (владеть собой...).
> - С фактами в руках, с цифрами в руках (обладая наглядными фактами, цифрами, наглядно их показывая).
> - Я не имел в руках документов и мне пришлось взять чужие бумаги...
> - Отдайте нам в руки полковников, мы сами их рассудим. А. Н. Толстой.
> - — Поправим как-нибудь. Все в наших руках. А. Островский.
> - Наложить на что-нибудь руку (завладеть).
> - Глафира еще при жизни матери успела понемногу забрать весь дом в руки. Тургенев.
> - На что родитель — медведь, и того к рукам прибрала. Мельников-Печерский.
> - ...соединили в своих руках обширные территории.
> - ...власть перешла в руки...
> - Быть под чьей-нибудь рукой (старинное).
> - ...объединил под своей рукой многие земли.
> - Когда-нибудь... все области, которые ты ныне изобразил так хитро на бумаге, все под руку достанутся твою. Пушкин...

Так же в словаре Евгеньевой есть:

> **Выдать на́ руки** — вручить, отдать что-л. непосредственно кому-л.
>
> **Из рук в руки или с рук на́ руки** (передать, перейти) — непосредственно от одного к другому.

Таким образом: руки — это символ обладания. «На руках» значит у кого-то в обладании. Есть у кого-то в наличии.

Так же отдать кому-то на руки, значит отдать непосредственно, отдать в руки конкретного человека.

На руках — в обладании, во власти, в наличии у какого-то конкретного человека, он как бы держит это руках (в переносном смысле), или ему дали что-то в руки (в прямом или переносном смысле).

Интересно только почему предлог «на», а не «в».